# MySQL selecting particular dates for output

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, where-clause

I'm making a crude appointment scheduler for fun.

I have a page that will display the available appointments.

I want to display only appointment that are 30 days out, aka a month and unbooked aka user_id = 0.

Booked appointments with have a user_id that is associated with their account.

I'm stuck on how to tell MySQL to only display appointment with dates that are between today and a month from today.

The page uses PHP and MySQL using PDO.

I'm the most comfortable with PDO that's why I'm using it.

What I have looked at using is DATE_ADD(), CURDATE() + INTERVAL, as well as what I have on the page

```
<?php
    //opens database path
    $db = new PDO(DB_PATH, DB_LOGIN, DB_PW);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    
    $today = array(date(Y), date(m), date(d));
    
    $result = $db->query("
SELECT * 
  FROM appt 
 WHERE DAY(date) < $today[3] 
   AND MONTH(date)=today[2]+1 
 ORDER 
    BY date DESC
     , time DESC
");
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td><input type='checkbox' name='id[]' value=".$row['id']."></td>";
        print "<td>".$row['date']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$row['time']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$row['doctor']."</td>";
        print "</tr>";
    }
  
  
  
  ?>
```

The database will be created as such

```
CREATE TABLE appts
  (key int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key
  , user_id int unsigned
  , date date
  , time time
  , doctor tinytext);
```

Comment: Consider storing date and time as a single entity

Comment: And see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: @Strawberry Why would that be better?

Answer (score 0):

> how to tell MySQL to only display appointment with dates that are between today and a month from today?

You can use MySQL date arithmetics. I think you want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM appt 
WHERE date >= current_date - interval 1 month
  AND date <  current_date + interval 1 day
ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC
```

Comment: current_date is the function or a variable defined earlier?

Comment: @user3831093: that's a MySQL built-in function that returns the current date (without time): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate